# Why tooltipPosition = "fixed" don't work (amCharts v4)

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

Why tooltipPosition = "fixed" don't work for my map?
I read the documentation and did as it says.
(https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/)

```js
function addSeries(country, tooltipHTML) {
    let newSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
    newSeries.useGeodata = true;
    newSeries.include = country;
    newSeries.mapPolygons.template.fill = am4core.color("#4D7EAA");
    newSeries.fill = am4core.color("#4D7EAA");
    newSeries.mapPolygons.template.tooltipText = tooltipHTML;
    newSeries.mapPolygons.template.tooltipHTML = tooltipHTML;
    newSeries.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
    newSeries.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#000");
    newSeries.tooltip.tooltipPosition = "fixed";
    newSeries.tooltip.x = 10;
    newSeries.tooltip.trackable = false;
    newSeries.tooltip.y = 30;
    newSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("over", over);
    newSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("out", out);
    newSeries.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.pointer;
    let hs = newSeries.mapPolygons.template.states.create("hover");
    hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#004685");
}
```

Full code:
https://codepen.io/nefayran/pen/BEmQvE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question.

Please note [the documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/#tooltipPosition_property) also says:

> Inherited from [Sprite](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/sprite/)

I.e. the property is not actually that of the `Tooltip` instance itself, rather it is a property & behavior a tooltip acquires from the object triggering it (not entirely unlike [`tooltipText`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/#tooltipText_property)).

Generally, there is 1 tooltip on a series that is shared between its objects, so even though in this case each `mapPolygon` triggers the tooltip, it's not a tooltip per polygon rather one shared on a series (almost like a singleton). This way, as you hover from mapPolygon to mapPolygon, the tooltip remains continuously visible and just changes properties accordingly.

So, in this case, instead of setting the property on the tooltip itself, just set it on the template for mapPolygons:

```js
// newSeries.tooltip.tooltipPosition = "fixed";
newSeries.mapPolygons.template.tooltip.tooltipPosition = "fixed";
```

Here's a fork:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/29890969c7222b7ddba5c9fbeefa80b5

#### Addendum (2019-04-17)

Problem: Hovering over the city (`mapImage`/its children) or line (`mapLine` or variant) kills the hover effect of the `mapPolygon` and the line/animation it triggers.

Solution: If the cities/lines don't have any user interaction features like a tooltip, my suggestion is to disable interactions altogether so hovering over them goes straight to the `mapPolygon` underneath, i.e.

```js
cities.mapImages.template.interactionsEnabled = false;
lineSeries.mapLines.template.interactionsEnabled = false;
```

The demo above has been updated to include those lines.

Comment: Thank you very much! There is one more problem, can you please tell me how to merge sprites so that they would have one hover effect, when you hover on the city, the animation disappears: (

Comment: @Nefayran You're very welcome! I've updated the answer, in this case I suggest `interactionsEnabled = false` on the appropriate templates.